# How to print curly brackets with new formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, output

I am trying to have python output something that I can then copy and past into a latex document. I need the output to look like this:

q_{00}
q_{01}

etc, I am using this code here, but, is there a way to get the curly bracket to print, the formatted number, and the other curly bracket, without adding whitespace or spaces?

```
for rows in range(nst):
    print("q_{{0:0=2d}}".format(rows))
```

which just yields `q_{0:0=2d}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{{` unescapes to an uninterpreted `{`, so you need another `{`:

```
for rows in range(nst):
    print("q_{{{0:0=2d}}}".format(rows))
```

Likewise for the closing `}`, of course.